# VSTS - Deny users to access another team backlog

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

I have 2 teams in my VSTS Project: Administrators and Developers.
I need to deny access to the Administrator Backlog to users inside of Developers.

Now any user has access to all teams backlogs and I can't find how to restrict this.

Anybody can help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can restrict the team users with **Area** Security.

Follow below steps to achieve that:

1. Create 2 Groups for the 2 teams: (Admin -> Security -> Create Group)

   e.g.: `AdminGP` for Administrators team, `DevGP` for Developers
   team.
2. Add the team users to the corresponding Group.
3. Navigate to Home project, then create `Areas` for each Team if no
   areas created before. (Admin -> Work -> Areas)

   e.g. `TeamAdmin` and `TeamDev` in below screenshot
4. Navigate to the specific Team, and [set the default Area path for
   the team](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/scale/set-team-defaults?view=vsts#set-team-default-area-paths).
5. Back to home project, Admin -> Work -> Areas, Right click the
   `AdminGP` area -> `Security`
6. Add the corresponding Groups for the teams, then set bellow
   permissions for `TeamDev` Group (Developers team):

   ```
   View permissions for this node - Deny

   View work items in this node - Deny
   ```

Thus the members in Developers team cannot see the Administrators team's work items in Backlog/Board.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try and let you know.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I've followed the steps, but still the users can see the Administrator backlog

Comment: @RodrigoMocca Make sure you have exactly followed the steps and you have added the develop users to the Dev group. Checked it again and that always working on my side.

Answer (score 4):

The answer here works, but what do you do when you get 5 teams?  100 teams? For each team, do you Deny permissions to the other 99?  Not very scalable.  So I tried to find another way and figured out what I think is a better approach.

My goal, btw, was to create a good user-experience for my stakeholders, and constrain what they are able to access and modify.  I personally feel that the members of the software engineering team should have access to and be able to contribute to any team... but that's personal opinion.

I got flummoxed, at first, by the fact that teams, when created, get added to Contributors... giving them access to all areas.  So first, remove the Team security group from the Contributors group.  Second, set the "View project-level information" permission to "Allow" for the team.  Last, edit security for the top-level Area associated with the team (sub-areas inherit permissions), add the team group to security for that Area, and "Allow" the following for the team group

- Edit work items in this node
- View work items in this node
- Manage test plans (if we want end-users involved in UAT work within Azure DevOps)
- Manage test suites (same)

This assumes, btw, that you've also assigned the top-level Area for that group to that team, and included sub-areas.

At this point, as a member of a team, a stakeholder will only see the teams they are members of, under "My Teams", when viewing boards, backlogs, and sprints.  They could go out of their way to browse any other board... but they wouldn't see anything because they don't have permissions to the items on those boards.

Then, I would assign the various stakeholders to the team(s) in which they had a stake. 
 One could also add software engineering members to teams as well, as this uses an "Allow" approach instead of a "Deny" approach, and so their "My Teams" list would include teams they were members of.  Personally, I'd probably go with allowing the engineers to control it themselves through "favorites", rather than having to administer adding \ removing engineers from team security groups.